# Fuzzy search where a space is omitted?

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

I am trying to write a fuzzy query that allows for missed spaces in Elasticsearch. I am going to use this for something rather complicated, so I made a simple test index to try stuff out on.

[Here's the link to the setup for the test index](https://gist.github.com/quietsamurai98/d62aeff427829d73c1e4f328ecffb988)

Each document is formatted like this:

```
"name": "CAT",
"altnames": [
  "CAT",
  "HOUSE CAT"
]
```

So far, I have written a query that can handle a misspelled altname such as "hose cat" instead of "house cat". This is the query:

```
GET /fuzzyanimals/animal/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [
          {
          "match": {
             "name": {
               "query": "HOSE CAT",
               "operator" : "and",
               "fuzziness": "1"
             }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
             "altnames": {
               "query": "HOSE CAT",
               "operator" : "and",
               "fuzziness": "1"
             }
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match" : 1
    }
  }
}
```

This query works perfectly for "HOSE CAT", returning the document for "CAT", but not "RAT" or "BAT". However, when you give it "HOUSECAT", it returns nothing. I assume this is because "HOSE CAT" is split into two strings ("HOSE" and "CAT"), and it searches for entries where both strings appear after fuzzing. If this is the case, how would one go about searching for "HOUSECAT" if the user left off the space?